# Redirect output of time command in unix into a variable in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I just want to capture the output of a time command i.e:

`X=$(time ls)`

or

`$(time ls) | grep real`

The time function spits it to the console though. How do I do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> X=`(time ls) 2>&1 | grep real`

Comment: You don't need a subshell just for `time`; Dennis Williamson's answer is better in that regard.

Answer (score 16):

See [BashFAQ/032](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/032).

```
$ # captures output of command and time
$ time=$( TIMEFORMAT="%R"; { time ls; } 2>&1 )    # note the curly braces

$ # captures the time only, passes stdout through
$ exec 3>&1 4>&2
$ time=$(TIMEFORMAT="%R"; { time ls 1>&3 2>&4; } 2>&1)
bar baz
$ exec 3>&- 4>&-
```

The time will look like "0.000" using `TIMEFORMAT="%R"` which will be the "real" time.

Comment: could you explain a little how this works ? I've uses a snippet like this cargo cult style for years. Whats stream 3 and 4 ? and the '-' ?

Comment: @Sirex: Streams 3 and 4 are streams created by the `exec` command in my answer using available file descriptors. Any available file descriptors could be used. Streams 3 and 4 are copies of 1 (`stdout`) and 2 (`stderr`), respectively. This allows the output of `ls` to pass normally to `stdout` and `stderr` via 3 and 4 while the output of `time` (which normally goes to `stderr`) is redirected to the original `stdout` (1) and then captured in the variable using command substitution. As you can see in my example, the filenames `bar` and `baz` are output to the terminal. ...

Comment: ...  Once finished, the extra streams are closed using the trailing `-`.

Comment: Running this with tracing mode (`set -x`) adds some unwanted output to the result. I solved it by adding `set +x` so that scripts won't fail while debugging. So the solution that worked for me: `time=$(set +x; TIMEFORMAT="%R"; { time ls 1>&3 2>&4; } 2>&1)`

Answer (score 5):

Time writes its output to STDERR rather than STDOUT.  Making matters worse, by default 'time' is a shell builtin command, so if you attempt 'time ls 2>&1' the '2>&1' only applies to 'ls'.

The solution would probably be something like:

```
/usr/bin/time -f 'real %e' -o OUTPUT_FILE ls > /dev/null 2>&1<br>
REALTIME=$(cat OUTPUT_FILE | cut -f 2 -d ' ')
```

There are more fancy ways to do it, but that is the clear/simple way.

Comment: I am interested in doing this without -o. Can you post one of the fancy methods you were thinking of :) ?

Answer (score 4):

The cleanest approach is to combine a **temp file** and use GNU's time.

```
command="sleep 1"
saved_timing=`mktemp`
/usr/bin/time --format="%E real" -o "$saved_timing" $command
elapsed=$(cat "$saved_timing")
echo $elapsed
```

This will not bypass normal command output and you don't have to care about the file either since it will be deleted on it own.

Comment: this should be the accepted solution

Answer (score 2):

@Dennis Williamson's answer is great, but it doesn't help you store the command's output in one variable, and the output of `time` in another variable. This is actually not possible using file descriptors.

If you want to record how long a program takes to run, you could do this by just subtracting the start time from the end time. Here is a simple example that shows how many milliseconds a program took to run:

```
START_TIME=$(date +%s%3N)
OUTPUT=$(ls -l)
ELAPSED_TIME=$(expr $(date +%s%3N) - $START_TIME)
echo "Command finished in $ELAPSED_TIME milliseconds"
```

This is not quite as accurate as the `time` command, but it should work perfectly fine for most bash scripts.

Unfortunately Mac's `date` command doesn't support the `%N` format, but you can install `coreutils` (`brew install coreutils`) and use `gdate`:

```
START_TIME=$(gdate +%s%3N)
OUTPUT=$(ls -l)
ELAPSED_TIME=$(expr $(gdate +%s%3N) - $START_TIME)
echo "Command finished in $ELAPSED_TIME milliseconds"
```